# Organize in sequence cell with same value vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to make a code in VBA to group in sequence cells with the same value (string), for exemple I have a giant workbook with 4 costumers in a random order and want to group them (as the image), I am trying but don't even know how to start the logical sequence. It will be between 8 and 10 costumers.

Before - [image: example before]

After - [image: Example after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("A:A").Sort Range("A1"), xlAscending
```

You can find info on how to tweak the `Range.Sort` method to fit the needs of your actual data [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort). You will need to code for the size (Column Span) of the used range, header, etc.

---

Comment: I totally forgot about the Sort command, I recorded a macro with me doing the sort way and worked perfectly. Thanks